# How to select last element with last() without going through sub elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to change the `background-color` attribute of the last `li` in my `ul` with id **list1** (the li after "list item 4"). However, if i run `$( "ul#list1 li" ).last().css( "background-color", "red" );` then the function is selecting the very last `li`, which is **list2 item1**.

Is there a way to tell the function to not run through sub elements?

```js
 
$( "ul#list1 li" ).last().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1">
  <li>list1 item 1</li>
  <li>list1 item 2</li>
  <li>list1 item 3</li>
  <li>list1 item 4</li>
  <li>
      <ul>
        <li>list2 item 1</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) method which traverses only direct children.

```js
 
$( "ul#list1").children().last().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1">
  <li>list1 item 1</li>
  <li>list1 item 2</li>
  <li>list1 item 3</li>
  <li>list1 item 4</li>
  <li>
      <ul>
        <li>list2 item 1</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

**JS**

```js
$( "ul#list1 > li:last-child" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1">
  <li>list1 item 1</li>
  <li>list1 item 2</li>
  <li>list1 item 3</li>
  <li>list1 item 4</li>
  <li>
      <ul>
        <li>list2 item 1</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can also do it via css, you also need to use `>` to determine which child you want to use.

**CSS**

```css
ul#list1 > li:last-child{
  background-color : red;
  }
```

```html
    <ul id="list1">
      <li>list1 item 1</li>
      <li>list1 item 2</li>
      <li>list1 item 3</li>
      <li>list1 item 4</li>
      <li>
          <ul>
            <li>list2 item 1</li>
          </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Just add `>`, so it understands that it will look at the `li` directly under it and not including the last `li` in it's child nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`:last-child`](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)

```
$("#list1:last-child").css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Comment: However, the solution is `:last-child` without doubt

Answer (score 1):

```js
$( "ul#list1 li:not(ul#list1 li ul li)" ).last().addClass('red')
```

```css
.red{background-color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1">
  <li>list1 item 1</li>
  <li>list1 item 2</li>
  <li>list1 item 3</li>
  <li>list1 item 4</li>
  <li>
      <ul>
        <li>list2 item 1</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Define `:not(ul#list1 li ul li)` then add class with style

Comment: @EdwardBlack glad to help happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `$( "#list1 li:last-child" ).prev().css( "background-color", "red" );` to select `list1 item 4`

```js
$( "#list1 li:last-child" ).prev().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1">
  <li>list1 item 1</li>
  <li>list1 item 2</li>
  <li>list1 item 3</li>
  <li>list1 item 4</li>
  <li>
      <ul>
        <li>list2 item 1</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This selects the previous last element, not the last.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

$( "ul#list1 > li:last" ).css( "background-color", "red" );

```js
$( "ul#list1 > li:last" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1">
  <li>list1 item 1</li>
  <li>list1 item 2</li>
  <li>list1 item 3</li>
  <li>list1 item 4</li>
  <li>
      <ul>
        <li>list2 item 1</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No, this also selects "list2 item1"

Comment: I actually try to access the last li, but if you remove the `prev()` then it should be working like i expected.

Comment: Oh, you were targeting the list after **list1 item4**.

Comment: Done, I guess this is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```js
var li = $( "ul#list1 li" );
var subLiLength = $("ul#list1 ul li").length;
li.eq(li.length - subLiLength - 1).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1">
  <li>list1 item 1</li>
  <li>list1 item 2</li>
  <li>list1 item 3</li>
  <li>list1 item 4</li>
  <li>
      <ul>
        <li>list2 item 1</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```